# Restrict number of times the file extension appears in e-mail macro attachment

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code below, which adds the file extension to the name of the attachment.  This is fine as long as the file is only sent once - as had been the case in a previous application of this code.  However I now need to potentially have the file updated and then resent onwards, BUT when I run the code below, I end up with a file which has the file extension added to the name of the attachment several times.  (file.xlsm.xlsm.xlsm, etc.)

How can I change the code below to stop this happening - totally stuck and have managed to break the whole thing twice now!

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook


If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
    If wb1.FileFormat = 51 And wb1.HasVBProject = True Then
        MsgBox "There is VBA code in this xlsx file. There will" & vbNewLine & _
               "be no VBA code in the file you send. Save the" & vbNewLine & _
               "file as a macro-enabled (. Xlsm) and then retry the macro.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

TempFileName = wb1.Name
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, _
                               Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = wb1.Sheets("Internal Use Only").Range("F7").Value
    .CC = wb1.Sheets("Supplier Details").Range("Q25").Value
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Audit Request processed"
    .Body = "some text"
    .Attachments.Add wb2.FullName
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False

' Delete the file.
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the file extension from the filename. Then you're appending the extension back to the filename, which already includes it (because that's where you got it from in the first place).

Just remove the extension from the filename after you get the extension.

Replace:

```
TempFileName = wb1.Name
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, _
                               Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))
```

With:

```
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, _
                               Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

TempFileName = Left(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - Len(FileExtStr))
```

Comment: Tried it and it doesn't work - adds the file extension back on again , is perhaps this but of code the issue.                       Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)

Comment: @RobertW081171 It would be helpful if you post some examples of what your filenames start out as, what they are after the first time you run it, etc.

Comment: The one in question is Audit request Form.xlsm.  when I run the macro which in effect mails the form to the person who needs to approve the request, the attachment becomes Audit request From.xlsm.xlsm.    I then have another macro which will then generate a log number, and then once approved send the form Back to the original requestor, but this time the attachment becomes Audit request From.xlsm.xlsm.xlsm.  It all gets a biut ridiculous and seeing as this form may well go externally from my workplace I need to get this neat and tidy, as it looks unprofessional.

Comment: What are the actual variable's values by the time you save the workbook? If you put this line `MsgBox "TempFilePath: " & TempFilePath & vbNewLine & "TempFileName: " & TempFileName & vbNewLine & "FileExtStr: " & FileExtStr` before the `wb1.SaveCopyAs` line then run it, what does it show?

Comment: TempFilePath: C:\Users\wilsonra\AppData\Local|Temp  (I Assume this is largely irrelevant).  TempFileName: Audit request form.xlsm  FileExtStr: .xlsm

Comment: Well, there's your issue. The filename variable has the extension already in it. You're appending the extension to the filename when saving the workbook, which doubles up that extension. What do you see if you do the run the same msgbox with the code I gave in my answer?

Comment: That code does the same thing - it appends the file extension to the file name.  I've tried to remove the file extension variable, and also amended the wb1 and wb2 names to no effect.  as I said originally I am stuck on how to stop the continued addition of the file type.

Comment: Are you positive it does the same thing? You've correctly swapped the positions of those two lines? Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Josh,  you are correct (I had been putting the code in the wrong place!) I now get the file name without the extension and then the file extension.  However this seems to have created another issue where I no longer seem to be able to create wb2 via the code and I am left with an error at the end due to a missing item (wb2) and no attachment on the e-mail.

Comment: Its OK I found a work around - I have used this to request the user defines the name (if they don't we can live with the duplicate extensions and fix when we return the form to the original user).     TempFileName = Application.InputBox("Please name file as: - Audit Request - (Your Organisation/Facility Name) - (No Special Characters are allowed!)", _
    "File Name", Type:=2, Default:=DefaultName)
    
    If TempFileName = False Then Exit Sub 'Handle if user cancels